# Move children elements up one level with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to mover a nav element up one level so I end up with something like:

```
<div>
 <nav>
   <a href='#'>hello</a>
   <a href='#'>hello</a>
 </nav>
</div>
```

to

```
 <nav>
    <a href='#'>hello</a>
    <a href='#'>hello</a>
 </nav>
<div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to use unwrap(); with no success.

```
$('div > nav').unwrap();
```

Not entirely sure why.

Comment: you simply need to insert nav before div. if you unwrap it, the div will be removed.

Comment: It doesn't work because that's not what unwrap does. Have you read the docs? Have you researched the docs for other methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unwrap` will unwrap your nav means it will remove the div from DOM. Try something like this.

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.before($div.children('nav')); 
//$div.before($div.children()); //For all children use children()
```

if you have multiple then try this way:

```
$(function(){ //Make sure it is inside DOM ready
     var $div = $('div:has("nav")');
     $div.before(function () {
          return $(this).children("nav");
    });
});
```

Comment: It will operate on all divs.

Comment: @user2736012 Thats not a reason to downvote. OP should be able to know which div he wants to operate on.

Comment: Maybe it's more than one set of `div > nav` elements. Maybe OP *doesn't* know any better.

Comment: @user2736012 Thats not what is in the question it says `mover a nav element up one level` If that is so, is it difficult to put it in a loop?

Comment: It also says "move children elements up", yet there's only one `nav` child. No it's not difficult to put it in a loop, which is what you should do.

Comment: @user2736012 It depends upon how you interpret.

Comment: Right. OP is clearly confused, and posting an answer that will give odd results isn't helpful. What we do know is that there is a relationship between at least one `div > nav`. So that is what should be targeted.

Comment: Ok, I actually don't mind removing the div element from the dom, as long as nav and all of it's contents are one level up.

Comment: @KyleJoseph if you do unwrap it will move up, means your div will be removed so it obviously going to move up.

Comment: @user2736012 Check out my update on targetting only the ones that has nav.

Answer (score 5):

You should try `insertBefore()` more info: http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

```
$("nav").insertBefore("div");
```

If you have multiples and want to make sure it is moved up one level and not to just any `div` and only it's `parent` try this:

```
$("div > nav").each(function (){
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent());
});
```

If they aren't all inside `div` then just do:

```
$("nav").each(function (){
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('nav').insertBefore($('nav').parent());`

This will move the element one up.

Js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tsuUE/

You'll likely want to give your `nav` and `id` to select only that element.

Comment: I like this answer best, since you don't need to know the parent element (decoupling). John Gerdsen's answer also does this.

Comment: I agree, you shouldn't have to know what's wrapping it.  What if you change that element later?  If you like it vote for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked wonderfully in my case, where I had to reposition a div selected (via its class) up a level.

```
$(".className").each(function (){
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent());
});
```